# control characters in vi

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a Makefile for compiling some Fortran files. In the Makefile, there were lines which were tab spaced. Recently I noticed that a few such lines have changed and they start with ^I, e.g.

previous file, line 2:

```
 sdc_j1
```

and that line has become:

^Isdc_j1 -in the new file.

Now I do not remember putting a weird character at the start of a line in that Makefile. I am not understanding that how did I ended up with this weird "^I" character.

P.S. the new Makefile is a copy of the old Makefile. They were not created in the same directory, i.e. I had initially: /home/sdc/Makefile - this is the old file location and then I copied that to another directory: /mjm/sdc/Makefile and there I noticed the change. Can anyone tell me what might have happened here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `^I` is a tab: https://superuser.com/questions/301345/what-is-the-i-character-and-how-do-i-find-it-with-sed

Comment: You can toggle that mode (displaying unprintable characaters) with ":set invlist"

Comment: without typing ":set invlist", that "^I" is appearing in my file. Also by doing ":set invlist", the characters are shown in color which is different from the normal text color of that file, generally.